# Sudoku Solver algorithm for int[,]

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, int, sudoku, solver

Good day to all,

I've been working on a C# Sudoku Solver application but I sincerely underestimated the difficulty of the algorithms to solve a sudoku. I've been searching the web for possible algorithms that I could implement, but I've had no luck finding an easy algorithm that I can get my head around.

I found an algorithm that may work in my application, however this person is using a single-dimensional array to work it out.
I've tried to change it to make it work with a multidimensional array, but I can't get it to work properly.

Could anybody give me advice or show me how I could change the code so that it works with a multidimensional array(int[,])? I just can't seem to find it on my own. The code is found here: http://blah.winsmarts.com/2007-1-sudoku_solver_in_c-.aspx

If you have another algorithm that would work with an int[,], that's also wonderful of course.

Help would be greatly appreciated since I've been searching for a long time.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Then write a method to change your 2d array to 1d and use that code.

Comment: Algorithm to solve a Sudoku? All I did was teach my computer the rules of Sudoku, then brute-force it, lol.

Comment: Yes but I'm not smart enough to create such things yet. I'm quite a beginner-programmer you see:). I'm even struggling to get what I want with Tim S.' idea.

Comment: You should read my series of articles on a simple graph colouring algorithm in C#. The last episode in the series will be of particular interest to you, but start from the beginning. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/graph+colouring/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you linked already logically uses a 2D array, it just uses a 1D array as a backing.  Change this:

```
private int[] vals = new int[81];
public int this[int row, int column]
{
    get { return vals[FindIndex(row, column)]; }
    set
    {
        vals[FindIndex(row, column)] = value;
    }
}

private int FindIndex(int row, int column)
{
    return (((column - 1) * 9) + row - 1);
}
```

To:

```
private int[,] vals = new int[9,9];
public int this[int row, int column]
{
    get { return vals[row - 1, column - 1]; }
    set
    {
        vals[row - 1, column - 1] = value;
    }
}
```

(The `- 1`'s are necessary with the rest of the current code because `row` and `column` start at 1 instead of 0.)

Comment: You're right, it actually uses a logical 2D array. I'm going to try out your way, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Recursive backtracking , brute force, algorithm.

```
public class SudokoSolver
{
    private readonly Grid _grid;

    public SudokoSolver(Grid grid)
    {
        _grid = grid;
        _grid.Validate();
    }

    public int?[,] SolvePuzzle()
    {
        Solve();
        Console.WriteLine(_grid.Assigns + " tries total.");
        return _grid.Data;
    }

    private bool Solve()
    {
        int row, col;
        if (!_grid.FindUnassignedLoc(out row, out col))
        {
            return true;
        }

        for (int num = 1; num <= 9; num++)
        {
            if (_grid.NoConflicts(row, col, num))
            {
                _grid.Assign(row, col, num);

                if (Solve())
                {
                    return true;
                }
                _grid.Unassign(row, col);
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public int?[,] Data
    {
        get { return _grid.Data; }
    }
}

public class Grid
{
    public int?[,] Data { get; private set; }
    private int _curC = 0;
    private int _curR = 0;
    private int _assigns = 0;

    public Grid(int?[,] data)
    {
        Data = data ?? new int?[9,9];
    }
    public bool FindUnassignedLoc(out int row, out int col)
    {
        while (Data[_curR, _curC].HasValue)
        {
            _curC++;

            if (_curC == 9)
            {
                _curR++;
                _curC = 0;
            }

            if (_curR == 9)
            {
                row = -1;
                col = -1;
                return false;
            }
        }

        row = _curR;
        col = _curC;

        return true;
    }

    public bool NoConflicts(int row, int col, int num)
    {
        for (int r = 0; r < 9; ++r)
        {
            if (Data[r, col] == num)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        for (int c = 0; c < 9; c++)
        {
            if (Data[row, c] == num)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        int fromC = 3 * (col/3);
        int fromR = 3 * (row / 3);

        for (int c = fromC; c < fromC + 3; c++)
        {
            for (int r = fromR; r < fromR + 3; r++)
            {
                if (Data[r, c] == num)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    public void Assign(int row, int col, int num)
    {
        _assigns++;
        Data[row, col] = num;
    }

    public void Unassign(int row, int col)
    {
        Data[row, col] = null;
        _curC = col;
        _curR = row;
    }

    public int Assigns
    {
        get { return _assigns; }
    }

    public void Validate()
    {
        if (Data.Length != 81)
        {
            throw new Exception("Invalid dimentions!");
        }

        if (!IsLegal())
        {
            throw new Exception("Illigal numbers populated!");
        }
    }

    public bool IsLegal()
    {
        var container = new HashSet<int>();
        //vertical check 
        for (int c = 0; c < 9; ++c)
        {
            container.Clear();
            for (int r = 0; r < 9; ++r)
            {
                if (Data[r, c].HasValue)  
                {
                    if (container.Contains(Data[r, c].Value))
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                    container.Add(Data[r, c].Value);
                }
            }
        }
        // horizontal check
        for (int r = 0; r < 9; ++r)
        {
            container.Clear();
            for (int c = 0; c < 9; ++c)
            {
                if (Data[r, c].HasValue)
                {
                    if (container.Contains(Data[r, c].Value))
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                    container.Add(Data[r, c].Value);
                }
            }
        }

        // square check
        var topLeftCorners = new List<Tuple<int, int>>
        {
            new Tuple<int, int>(0,0),
            new Tuple<int, int>(0,3),
            new Tuple<int, int>(0,6),
            new Tuple<int, int>(3,0),
            new Tuple<int, int>(3,3),
            new Tuple<int, int>(3,6),
            new Tuple<int, int>(6,0),
            new Tuple<int, int>(6,3),
            new Tuple<int, int>(6,6)
        };

        foreach (var topLeftCorner in topLeftCorners)
        {
            int fromC = topLeftCorner.Item2;
            int fromR = topLeftCorner.Item1;

            container.Clear();

            for (int c = fromC; c < fromC + 3; c++)
            {
                for (int r = fromR; r < fromR + 3; r++)
                {
                    if (Data[r, c].HasValue)
                    {
                        if (container.Contains(Data[r, c].Value))
                        {
                            return false;
                        }
                        container.Add(Data[r, c].Value);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: please explain detilas of your question.

Comment: brute force algorithm, with backtracking. start assigning from (0,0) -> (0,1) -> (0,2) ...  until all is filled. If at some point, options are exhausted, backtrack to previous assign etc ..

Comment: I've seen shorter more concise code like on the GeeksForGeeks website

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sudoku-backtracking-7/

The site also has other ways of solving Sudoku like backtracking, recursive and n-branch resolution